# Testing the relative signifance of variables in glm

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, anova, hypothesis-test

I am working through the practical sheet at this link: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~rds37/teaching/statistical_modelling/Practical6.pdf

In exercise 3, it is stated that to test whether the mother's myopia and father's myopia is equally significant, we must create a new variable

```
mumORdadMyopic <- (dadMyopic == "Yes") | (mumMyopic == "Yes")
```

and then fit the model with the variables dadMyopic, mumORdadMyopic. Using the previous exercises as a guide, we'd then perorm

```
data_1 <- myopic %>% dplyr::select(-compH, -TVHR)
data_2 <- myopic %>% dplyr::select(-compH, -TVHR, -mumMyopic) %>% cbind(mumORdadMyopic))

model_1 <- glm(myopic ~ ., data = data_1, family = binomial)
model_2 <- glm(myopic ~ ., data = data_2, family = binomial)

anova(model_1, model_2, test = "LR")
```

My question is this:

With the aim of testing whether mumMyopic and dadMyopic are equally significant variables, why is the above what we want to perform? I would have thought that we would want to fit one model without mumMyopic, and one without dadMyopic, and compare the performance of the models.

```
newdata_1 <- myopic %>% dplyr::select(-compH, -TVHR, -dadMyopic)
newdata_2 <- myopic %>% dplyr::select(-compH, -TVHR, -mumMyopic)

newmodel_1 <- glm(myopic ~ ., data = newdata_1, family = binomial)
newmodel_2 <- glm(myopic ~ ., data = newdata_2, family = binomial)

anova(newodel_1, newmodel_2, test = "LR")
```

where if newmodel_1 and newmodel_2 are significantly different (in a statistical sense), we could reject the hypothesis that mumMyopia and dadMyopia have the same predictive power.

Can someone explain why my suggested approach doesn't achieve what I want, and why the exercise's intended approach is the right one?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get it, why are you not checking the p-value of your variables from a glm model to check for significance? Why are you splitting up the data? Did you mean to do an ANOVA?

Comment: Just looking at the p values tells you the significance of each variable in the presence of each other. But in reality are the two variables equally significant?

Comment: What does `are the two variables equally significant` mean?